# How to check whether selected range made across the paragraph or not?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, epub

Am working on an  e_pub reader ios app. For highlight the selected text I am calling the javascript after selected the text, by surrounding the selected text with a span tag. My problem is is the selection happens within the paragraph, highight happens, if it made across the paragraph it doesn't work because of intermediate `<p>` tag. How to check whether the selected range has any html tags or not ?

Comment: you need to use regular expression to search html tag inside content

Comment: But when am passing the range it holds only the text . so regex validation fails.       function validhighlight(highvalue)
{
    alert(highvalue);
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
   return regex.test(highvalue);
}

Comment: tanq @Wellwisher. finally i fixed by regex match of "\n". Selected content only received the "\n" not any html tags

Answer (score 0):

instead of searching you can remove all html tag inside your content. simply by using jquery

```
var content = "<div>This Text contains <p> Some P tags</p> and <span> span tag </span></div>";
console.log($(content).text());
```

so you can remove all tags and wrap with your content with span then apply highlight.

Comment: as i mentioned above , its an epub reader. So user simply drag drop and click on highlight.. If the selection made beyond paragraph , span doesnt works.. so far i observed i didnt receive the HTML tags tags..